# Printing out file/folder permissions

Tags: python

I need a solution how to print out file permissions in a python script. The idea is to pass shell command `$: ls -l` to a python script, from where I'll print out the lines with "additional explanation". For example

`-rwxrwxr-x`

The additional explanation would be:

`Owner of the file has reading rights, writing right, but doesn't have execution rights.
Group has reading rights, writing right and execution rights.`

So, instead of covering all the possible cases of who has what rights, is there any easier way to do this besides checking each case with an `if` conditional?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly are you asking about? How to get access bits for a file or how to print them in the human friendly format?

Comment: Can you show your attempt at the solution?

Comment: Split into 3 groups of 3 characters (ignoring the sticky bit) - then you call a function passing the 3 chars to describe plus a name ("owner" or "group" or "everyone else"). What's the difficulty?

Comment: Well, that's the thing: the only idea I had for this was to cover cases in a sense that I would take out each character, do a comparison and print out the appropriate info. (If second character was 'r', print out 'Owned has reading rights')

So yes, i was hoping for a more friendly human format, one that I would make. That's why I didn't write an approach; it seemed exhausting and a poor solution.

Comment: BTW, it's generally considered bad practice to parse the output of `ls`, as discussed in [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls). And it's quite unnecessary in Python since there are various ways to get that info directly using functions in the `os` module, eg [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat)

Comment: use `os.stat(path)` to check single file/directory permissions

Comment: I figured, but it's the exercise I've been tasked with.

Comment: @monolith937 try to think of a better solution first and provide some code, otherwise it looks like pls do my homework.

Comment: I was afraid it might come off like that, but the question could've been: is there a built-in method for printing out file permissions in a human friendly format. So far I haven't had much luck with google searches

Comment: Ok, if your assignment is to parse the output of `ls` then I guess you'd better do that. :) But _please_ make sure your teacher takes a look at the U&L link I posted earlier and the BashGuide article [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (which is linked at the start of the U&L question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started.

We first create a list named `modes` containing all the combinations of who has the permission and the kind of permission they have. Then we loop over the mode string and our `modes` list in parallel, grabbing the associated combination from `modes` if the mode string doesn't have a `-` in that position.

```
modes = [(who, kind) for who in ('user', 'group', 'others') 
    for kind in ('read', 'write', 'execute')]

def explain_modestring(modestring):
    return ', '.join([' can '.join(t) 
        for c, t in zip(modestring[1:], modes) if c != '-'])

for s in ('-rwxrwxrwx', '-rwxr-xr--', '-r--------'):
    print(s, explain_modestring(s))
```

**output**

```
-rwxrwxrwx user can read, user can write, user can execute, group can read, group can write, group can execute, others can read, others can write, others can execute
-rwxr-xr-- user can read, user can write, user can execute, group can read, group can execute, others can read
-r-------- user can read
```

Comment: Yes, this is the exact output I was aiming to accomplish. Much appreciated